# respond with status code 410 from asp.net mvc for legacy .asp page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using asp.net mvc 4.0. I need to respond with 410 status code for specific legacy page: oldpage.asp

here is my web.config to handle error pages

```
 <system.web>

    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/500.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.aspx"/>
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/500.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>


  </system.web>

 <system.webServer>

    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="404.html" responseMode="File"/>
      <remove statusCode="500"/>
      <error statusCode="500" path="500.html" responseMode="File"/>
    </httpErrors>


  </system.webServer>
```

Here is my code in global.asax. I want to distinguish between .asp and .aspx requests, but .asp requests never make it here and I always get 404 for it.

```
  void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
        {

            string reqURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower();

            if(reqURL.Contains("/oldpage.asp") && !reqURL.Contains("/oldpage.aspx")){
                Response.Status = "410 Gone";
                Response.StatusCode = 410;
                Response.Write(Response.Status);
                Response.End();
            }
}
```

The code in global.asax never gets executed if my request ends with .asp, it works for other requests. What should I change to handle this?

Comment: `.asp` is not handled by `ASP.Net`. If it's just one specific page, then why don't you just handle the `response` in that single (asp) page?

Comment: I guess that works - thanks!

Comment: All I put in the .asp page is:<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
    Response.Status = "410 Gone"    
    Response.Write(Response.Status)
    Response.End
%>